# surface.fill() updating rect in while loop?

Tags: pygame, blit

I have two programs below trying to draw a ball on a yellow screen. One where my surface object is being filled outside of the while loop, and one that is being filled inside of the while loop.

When I have `.fill()` outside the while loop my image gets redrawn when I try to move it. So when the image goes down, it draws a duplicate image just 10 pixels further down the screen.

When I have `.fill()` inside the while loop my single image gets updated and redrawn to a new location.

Why is this?

Non-trailing code:

```
import pygame
import sys

length = 1200
width = 800


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((length, width))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

ball = pygame.image.load('ball.bmp')
ball_rect = ball.get_rect()
ball_rect.y = ball_rect.width
ball_rect.x = screen_rect.centerx


while True: 
    screen.fill((255, 255, 103))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ball_rect.y += 15

    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Trailing Image Code:

```
import pygame
import sys

length = 1200
width = 800


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((length, width))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
screen.fill((255, 255, 103))

ball = pygame.image.load('ball.bmp')
ball_rect = ball.get_rect()
ball_rect.y = ball_rect.width
ball_rect.x = screen_rect.centerx


while True: 


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ball_rect.y += 15

    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Please provide a [mcve] so we are able to assist. Code is better as text rather than an image so it's easier to run for others.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *text* of the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Does PyGame Trail the Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049561/why-does-pygame-trail-the-image)

Answer (score 1):

The linked code (image) does not produce the effect you describe.  In the left side, no updates are made to the `screen` at all.  On the right side, the only update made is the `screen.fill()` of yellow.

So hypothetically speaking ...

A PyGame program can be thought of as a type of *animation*.  During the main loop, there is typically a block for handling user-input, calls to update positions of on-screen objects, and calls to update, that is "re-paint" the screen.

Each "frame" of this animation is constructed with a background, plus typically some overlaid objects.  These might be things like a player-bitmaps, combatant bitmaps, play-field items, text scores & statuses, etc.  Generally the background is painted first, then the overlaid items.  Once the screen is drawn, the movement of the objects is calculated for the next display, it's re-drawn, and again & again...

The first situation the question describes is one where the screen is updated in a manner such that the previous "frame" of the animation has not been cleared away, and the user sees a composite of the previous and current display.

The second situation erases the entire display first, with the `screen.fill()`.  Thus removing any trace of the previous frame.  This is a typical handling.

There is yet another way.  This method keeps track of where the screen has been changed, and only the specific area that needs updating is re-painted.  This approach can potentially provide a much more efficient input-update-paint cycle, because it is not re-drawing items that have not changed.

Comment: The left code trails my image and the right code does not trail the image. But I think I understand what you are saying. Essentially, I have redraw the background every time there is movement from any of the overlaid objects?

Comment: Also - what is the other way that you describe?

Comment: Yes, pretty much, every frame - paint the background, paint the game objects.  Repeat.  The third way uses a concept generally known as "dirty" rectangles.  The part of the screen nedding updates is considered "dirty".  There's a short tutorial here - http://n0nick.github.io/blog/2012/06/03/quick-dirty-using-pygames-dirtysprite-layered/